# How can i search in a JSON file for a value with a string as key in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

I try to make a discord bot and i want to implement a voice call soundboard wich can play mp3 files from users. To store these files i need some information about the file. When its finished you should be able to play the files with a command like `!sound play test`. My question is: How can i search my JSON file after the Value key?

```
{       
    "test":{
        "owner":"some-id",
        "file":"mathemannsong.mp3",
        "stats":{
            "played": 0
        }
    },
    "test2":{
        "owner":"some-id",
        "file":"random.mp3",
        "stats":{
            "played": 5
        }
    }
}
```

This is my JSON file.

I want to search it like this:

```
cosnt file = require(".file.json")
const name = "test";
const owner = file.name.owner
```

I know why this dosn`t work.

Comment: I think you mean `const owner = file[name].owner`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `import` statement like below

```
Import * as file from 'file.json'
owner = file.name.owner
```